# Pass a value from one component to another component in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have to pass a value from index to the child component.

Index Page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from '../../containers/ChildComponent';
class IndexPage extends Component {
  render() {
    const name = 'Index';
    return (
      <ChildComponent name={name} />
    );
  }
}
export default IndexPage;
```

Child component:

```
import React from 'react';
const ChildComponent = () => {
  return (
    <p>{this.props.name}</p>
  );
 };
 export default ChildComponent;
```

Is there any workaround for this. Thank you.

Comment: please clarify your question. workaround for what exactly? (also child component will give you error, there is no prop input in the ChildComponent function and you do not need to use this.props -> just props.name )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a functional component as the child, there is no place for `this`

Destructing the props would be fine

```
const ChildComponent = ({name}) => {
  return (
    <p>{name}</p>
  );
 };
```

or

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>{props.name}</p>
  );
 };
```